# The bark on my 50 year old Japanese Maple splitting

Tags: trees, tree-care

I have a fifty year old Japanese Maple at my old house. I went to visit the tree and notice the bark on one of the lower trunks  had split was peeling away and now there were black circular marks, (not holes) on the bare tree[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tell us more details: Is this branch all dead or do you e.g. observe black spots on the leaves? Like this: https://www.treeserviceslittlerock.net/black-spots-maple-leaves/

Comment: What part of the world are you in? Can you add another photo from slightly further away so its possible to see more of the tree? Lastly, have you ever noticed any fungal growth such as toadstools/mushrooms/bracket fungus  nearby on the ground, at the base of the tree, or on the tree anywhere?

Comment: That bark has been dead for awhile. Could have been insects or disease.  Looks pretty bad for the tree depending on how much bark is in this condition.